# How to filter by timestamp using TableClient from @azure/data-tables

Tags: node.js, odata, azure-tableclient

I have an azure storage table which Im trying to filter by timestamp. I am using TableClient by @azure/data-tables to achieve this. I used odata query expression to do the filtering.

```
import { AzureNamedKeyCredential, TableClient } from "@azure/data-tables";

 const credential = new AzureNamedKeyCredential("AccountName", "AccountKey");
 const tableName = "SomeTable";
          
 const serviceClient = new TableClient(      `https://${connectionObject.AccountName}.table.core.windows.net`,
     tableName,
     credential
 );

const page = await serviceClient
    .listEntities({
         queryOptions: {                             
            // filter: `RowKey ge 'someunixvalue'`, //this works   
            filter: `timestamp ge datetime'2022-06-27T02:57:35.1831423Z'` //this doesnt work.                               
         }
     })
   .byPage({ maxPageSize: 1000, continuationToken })
   .next();
```

I have confirmed that the data has a field called timestamp and the value is 2022-06-27T02:57:35.1831423Z for one of the entities. The value of page.value will be an empty array for the failed case whereas the passing case has values.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, uppercase T, and without a space between single quotes-- it's also highly advisable to use a partitionkey to prevent total table scans, assuming you have more than one partition key (you should):

```
let ents = client.listEntities({ queryOptions: {
        partitionKey: key_name,
        filter: "Timestamp lt datetime'2023-03-25T21:02:43.8445081Z'"
    }})
```